# Functions properties (quick question)

Tags: calculus, functions

When adding/subtracting/multiplying/dividing/compositing two functions, is the result always a function? If so then why?

This is a question simply out of curiosity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the domain is same then the result is yes( with some addition condition like for division not to be zero the denumerator and special for compotisiting functions). You can go by definition to show that every element of domain has a unique image.

Comment: You can see [Function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Function_composition) and [Real-valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Real-valued_functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

---

Long answer: yes, by definition. If $f$ and $g$ are functions, then $f+g$ is, by *definition*, equal to the function that maps $x$ to $g(x)+f(x)$. It's the same for subtraction, multiplication and division.

The story is a little different with composition (which is a more general operation that can be applied to all mappings, not only to those on sets that contain adition). There, you start with two mappings, $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$, and you construct a new mappings, $g\circ f:A\to C$, which is defined as the mapping that transform $a$ to $g(f(a))$.

---

Note that out of all the operations, composition is unique in the fact that often, you can only construct $g\circ f$ but not $f\circ g$. You can only make compositions both ways if $A=B$, and in the case of real functions, you usually have $A=B=C=\mathbb R$ or some subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So if I can construct $g \circ f$ the result is always a function?

Comment: @Michael If $g$ and $f$ are functions, then yes.

Comment: Division $f(x)/g(x)$ may not be a function for $x$ such that $g(x) = 0$

Comment: @progo depends on the definition really. This is an area so rife with abuse of notation that it's hard to tell. Already in this answer many extra assumptions are made (f and g are functions to a group with addition for example. (note that they might be function from pretty much anyplace. Consider $f$ being the age of a person seconds and $g$ their height in cm.) In general the abuse of notation says that $f/g$ is defined where ever $g$ is non 0. Also a function can't "not be a function" for a specific value of input. It's either a function or isn't.

Answer (score 2):

A function associates to every value in the domain exactly one value in the codomain.

Addition, subtraction, multiplication and division are functions (of two arguments).

The composition of two functions is a function because the uniqueness of the values carries over.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you could say that a function is a triplet of objects $f, A, B$ such that $A$ and $B$ are sets and $f$ is a relation such that $\forall a\in A \exists ! b\in B | f(a)=b$, that is to say that $\textit{the image}$ of an element $a$ is one and only element $f(a)=b$ in B.

As a consequence, if you were to define the composition $\ f\circ g$ of $\ f:A \rightarrow B$ and $g: C \rightarrow D$, you would have to make sure that $g$ is able to relate elements of $Im(f)=\{b\in B | \exists a\in A : b=f(a)\}$ to elements of D, that is equivalent to saying that $Im(f)\subseteq C$.
That being said, if you were to define $f+g$, you would need $A=C$ and $B=C$, and you would need to define the operation '+' in $B=D$. The same goes for another operation.